# Three.js Raycast not producing intersections

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to produce a list of intersections of an object from a raycast, I keep getting a empty array back from intersectObjects() despite the ray intersecting the object. Any help would be much appreciated. Please see the fiddle and the below code https://jsfiddle.net/4dcfsvL6/

```
var rayStart = {
  x: 1180.0475900351605,
  y: 900.491932895052,
  z: 50.01035975094526,
 };
var rayEnd = {
  x: 1162.0475900351605,
  y: 930.491932895052,
  z: 15.01035975094526,
 };
const rayStartV = new THREE.Vector3(
  rayStart.x - xMin - (xRange / 2),
  rayStart.y - yMin - (yRange / 2),
  rayStart.z - zMin - (zRange / 2),
);
const rayEndV = new THREE.Vector3(
  rayEnd.x - xMin - (xRange / 2),
  rayEnd.y - yMin - (yRange / 2),
  rayEnd.z - zMin - (zRange / 2),
);
const directionV = new THREE.Vector3(
  rayEnd.x - rayStart.x,
  rayEnd.y - rayStart.y,
  rayEnd.z - rayStart.z,
);
scene.updateMatrixWorld();
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(rayStartV, directionV);
scene.add(new THREE.ArrowHelper(raycaster.ray.direction, raycaster.ray.origin, 300, 0xff0000) );
var intersects = raycaster.intersectObjects( [obj], true );
console.log(intersects)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed an important part in [`Raycaster`](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/core/Raycaster)'s documentation::

> `direction` — The direction vector that gives direction to the ray. **Should be normalized.**

You have to normalize the direction vector:

<s>`var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(rayStartV, directionV);`</s>

```js
var raycaster = new THREE.Raycaster(rayStartV, directionV.normalize());
```